# Change Jfoenix TabbedPane Header Color

Tags: java, css, javafx, jfoenix

How to change jfoenix tabbedpane default header color?
[jFoenix TabbedPane Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz6zE.png)

Only tabs color changes.
[Colored Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tpYY.png)

Comment: show your work, what you have tried for it?

Comment: @GautamRai i ve tried to change background color of jFoenix tabbedpane but only the body gets affected and not the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using css:

```
.tab{
-fx-background-color:red;
}

.tab-header-background{
-fx-background-color:red;
}
```

So far this is all i can do for you. If you have any questions ask them.

Comment: Wrong, inline styles can't include selectors.